# Navigation Bar not showing color and bar button item on adding MMDrawerController

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, mmdrawercontroller

I have added `MMDrawerController` to my project,before using `MMDrawerController` the navigation bar was appearing as desired in black color and the bar button item was also visible but when I added `MMDrawerController` to the project ,the navigation bar shows grey color rather than showing black and the bar button item also doesn't come .Kindly help me to get the navigation bar in black color and bar button item also visible.Thanks in advance!

[image: navigation bar settings]

[image: output on simulator]

//MARK: function for adding MMDrawer controller
 func buildNavigationDrawerInterface () {

```
    let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as!UITabBarController

    centerVC.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    let leftVCs = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController


    let leftSideNav =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftVCs)

    let centerSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerVC)

    drawerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: centerSideNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)

    drawerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
    drawerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView
    //centerContainer?.setDrawerVisualStateBlock(MMDrawerVisualState.swingingDoorVisualStateBlock())

    window!.rootViewController = drawerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
```

Comment: Try this self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black

Comment: Base navigation controller will be having grey color navigation bar. Try changing the color of navigation bar in Base Navigation controller in storyboard.

Comment: @Aditya Srivastava,already tried but no result

Comment: @Amit,no that is also black.

Comment: What is MMDrawer Controller? Perhaps include the code

Comment: @Benjamin Lowry,its a third party library added to add sidebar in app.

Comment: Okay well it's really hard to see what the issue might be here if you don't include any code.

Comment: Is that embedded in a NavigationController? If not, try embedding it in a navigation controller and see if that solves the issue

Comment: @Benjamin Lowry,code for adding sidebar is added,rest I have done everything through storyboard.

Comment: @Bruno Recilla,embeddednavigation controller also in that sidebar vc but no result.

Comment: By any chance, are you using the same NavigationBar color in all Views? If so, did you add any code to your Delegate to do that?

Comment: Ya,I am using same color for navigation bar but not added any code for it,just doing it through storyboard.